# subsetting all elements of a list by the same index values

Tags: r, list, subset

Probably trivial, but I didn't find a solution. I am trying to subset all elements of a list by the same index values.

Assuming my list is:
`mylist = list( seq(22,30,2),  c(1:5), rep(8,5))`

which gives me

```
[[1]]
[1] 22 24 26 28 30

[[2]]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

[[3]]
[1] 8 8 8 8 8
```

I am trying to extract only the values [2:4] and drop the other values of the element, so i get a list that looks like

```
[[1]]
[1]  24 26 28 

[[2]]
[1] 2 3 4 

[[3]]
[1] 8 8 8
```

I have tried a combination of foreach an lapply

`sub = foreach(i = c(1:3)) %do% {
        lapply(mylist, function(x){mylist[[i]][c(2:4)]})
}`

However I end up with a threefold replication

```
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] 24 26 28

[[1]][[2]]
[1] 24 26 28

[[1]][[3]]
[1] 24 26 28


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] 2 3 4

[[2]][[2]]
 [1] 2 3 4

[[2]][[3]]
[1] 2 3 4


[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
[1] 8 8 8

[[3]][[2]]
[1] 8 8 8

[[3]][[3]]
[1] 8 8 8
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

credit to @Richard Scriven

solution:

```
lapply(mylist, "[", 2:4)
```